# The events leading up to the Indominus Rex's escape

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world

I don't understand certain events that immediately precede the escape of the I. Rex in *Jurassic World*. They are:

1. **Why doesn't the paddock's control room have a terminal that can be used to monitor the implant's signals?** What is the point of the a redundancy monitoring system if it's not used?
2. There is merely a *possibility* that the I. Rex has escaped. **Why then do the characters move away from the safe paddock's control room while not knowing where the colossal predator is?** In particular, why do Owen and two workers enter into the paddock? More importantly, why does Claire drive off alone knowing full well of the possibility of an I Rex lurking somewhere? Why doesn't she just stay in the paddock's control room and call the main control room from where she is?

Are these plot holes or is there a way to rationalize them?

Comment: I thought the whole point was that the F-ed up... they were so frantic to find her that they missed/forgot about some of the things the computer systems could do.

Comment: To me this is a case of "__[Contrived Stupidity](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContrivedStupidityTropes)__". Right after the thermal scan comes up empty and Owen notices the scratch/claw marks, Claire rushes off while mentioning that the I-Rex has an implant in her back which she can track from the control room. Then it cuts to her in the car, _calling_ the control room, telling them to get the coordinates of the I-Rex. - I see no reason why Claire couldn't have just called the control room right away, but then the I-Rex's escape plan wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Even if they cannot track its implant from the paddock's control room, they should at least have had a telephone to call the main control room which can track _all_ implants across the entire park. Also, it allows the characters to be in the safest place for miles: a room with thick walls encased in a steel cage. That would be a nice place to stay until they figure out where the meanest dinosaur in the park currently is located.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good explanation given in the film why they don't have an implant tracking station in the I-Rex™ Control Room. They have visual *and* infra-red monitors and those seem to be completely effective, right up to the point that they (unexpectedly) stop working and everyone gets killed.

As to why they're dumb enough to go into the paddock, the answer is that the I-Rex™ is absolutely massive and should shine like a beacon on the IR scope. Without its new-found *visual and infra-red cloaking abilities* (which our heroes are of course unaware of) there should be absolutely no way that it could hide inside the paddock.

> *In a back corner, the paddock supervisor looked up from a magazine. **He
>   checked the infrared monitors but didn’t see the red outline of the
>   Indominus.** “Oh, boy…,” he muttered.*
>
> *Claire turned to him. “What? What are you saying?”*
>
> *“It doesn’t make sense,” the supervisor said. “The doors haven’t been opened in weeks.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Jurassic World: Special Edition Junior
>   Novelisation](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Jurassic_World_Special_Edition_Junior_Novelization)</sup></sub>

But yeah, going into the paddock without first checking the implant location was a monumentally stupid move. That being said, all the protagonists are depicted as *being* monumentally stupid, so it's not actually out of character.